# Accessing the values to monitor for checkpoint saving

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I would like to save the top-10 checkpionts along training. By checking documentations, setting `save_top_k`, `monitor` and `mode` options in [`ModelCheckpoint`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensions/generated/pytorch_lightning.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint.html?highlight=ModelCheckpoint) jointly seem to do the job.

But I am not sure what are the parameters available for the this callback to monitor. Are they logged values saved during `training_step()` or `validation_step()` through `self.log("loss", XYZ)`?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As in your example, `loss` can be use in monitor. Similarly, you can specify
`self.log("val_acc", X_variable)`.